# Check if a variable is equal to one or more values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to check if a variable used as a parameter in a stored procedure is equal to certain values from a certain table.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
if @inputvariable = (select columna from testtable 
                     where columnb = somevalue 
                       and columnc not in (somevalue, somevalue))
```

From the error I can see the issue is because the select statement returns more than 1 value. I'd trying to understand the correct syntax when the variable value can be one of multiple values

Comment: Change `=` to `IN`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *exists*

```
if exists (
  select * from TestTable 
  where ColumnB = SomeValue... and columnA = @InputVariable
)
begin
  Do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just switch from **=** to **in**

```
if @inputvariable IN (select columna from testtable 
                      where columnb = somevalue and 
                            columnc not in (somevalue,somevalue)
                     )
```

The second way is to use EXISTS from previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably quite a few ways to do this. Here's one way.

```
SELECT t.* INTO #t
FROM (SELECT 1 AS Value UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) AS t

SELECT * 
FROM #t

DECLARE @v INT

SET @v = 1
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 WHERE @v IN (SELECT Value FROM #t))
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Yes'
    END
        ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'No!'
    END

SET @v = 4
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 WHERE @v IN (SELECT Value FROM #t))
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Yes'
    END
        ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'No!'
    END
```